# C++ Дан массив слов. Заменить все буквы QQ на BB. Никак не получается =/

Tags: c++, строки, vector

Дан массив слов. Необходимо заменить все буквы QQ в словах, на буквы BB.(Например 4 слова) После чего, получить подстроку, взяв от
каждого слова массива длиной более 1 символа по
две конечных буквы. Сформировать предложение
из тех слов массива, которые не содержат в своем
составе символов из полученной подстроки.
Перерыл все форумы. Ничего не не помогает.
Пробовал через начальный этап делать через for_each, search, replace, find.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void myfunction(string & i)
{
    if (i == "QQ") i = "BB";

}
int main()
{
    vector<string> v;
    v.push_back("QQ");
    v.push_back("creamQQ");
    v.push_back("bQQbus");
    v.push_back("cQQb");
    v.push_back("QQcci");
    ostream_iterator<string> printit(cout, " ");

    cout << "Before replacing" << endl;
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), printit);

    for_each(v.begin(), v.end(), myfunction);

    cout << endl;
    cout << "After replacing" << endl;
    copy(v.begin(), v.end(), printit);
    cout << endl;

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

И даже как-то так, и все впустую =/

Comment: В myfunc вы сравниваете строку на точное совпадение, а вам нужно искать такую подстроку.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Думаю, вас устроит

```
void myfunction(string & i)
{
    for(auto idx = i.find("QQ"); idx != string::npos; idx = i.find("QQ"))
        i.replace(idx,2,"BB");
}
```

Это ответ на вопрос, вынесенный в заглавие - "заменить все QQ на BB".

> После чего, получить подстроку, взяв от каждого слова массива длиной
>   более 1 символа по две конечных буквы. Сформировать предложение из тех
>   слов массива, которые не содержат в своем составе символов из
>   полученной подстроки.

Вот это смущает. Если мы берем от каждого слова по 2 буквы, то любое слово будет автоматически содержать в себе как минимум 2 символа из полученной подстроки. Т.е. в результате мы не должны получить ничего. Вряд ли это то, что требуется, так что если вас интересует и эта часть - то уточните ее.

Answer (score 1):

Поиск строки:

```
for (std::vector<string>::iterator it = myvector.begin();
     it != myvector.end(); ++it)
{
    int found=it->find("QQ");
    if (found == std::string::npos) break;
    it->replace(found, 2, "BB");
}
```

Comment: Т.е. если в первой строке нет этого "Ку-ку", то в остальных и искать не надо? А если "Ку-ку" несколько?

Comment: добавить дополнительную проверку, это не сложно

Comment: И еще вдогонку - нужно либо писать `(*it).`, либо `it->`.

Comment: Конечно, несложно. Но если человек начинает писать вместо поиска `if (i == "QQ") i = "BB";`, то вряд ли он самостоятельно справится с этим...